# What is the 'Subtract Days' equivalent of DateTimePicker.Value.AddDays()?

Tags: c#

I have a DateTimePicker and two buttons on a form. The buttons are intended to allow a user to cycle backwards and forwards through the dates displayed in the picker.

The code DateTimePicker.Value.AddDays(1); increments the value displayed and DateTimePicker.Value.AddDays(-1); decrements it. It seems a bit clunky to me but this works as expected, is passing in a value of -1 the correct way to decrement the displayed date?

Why isn't there a SubtractDays() method?

Comment: Probably because all it would do is call AddDays(-1*x) which isn't terribly useful. If you really need it, write an extension method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've seen, you can use AddDays with a negative amount to subtract days, so there's no need for the extra methods (there would need to be one for each of the Add methods). If it really bothers you, you can write extension Subtract methods for all the Add methods.

For example

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static DateTime SubtractDays(this DateTime start, int days)
    {
        return start.AddDays(-days);
    }
}
```

Comment: Than you Richard for your informative reply.